# Query PHP to a Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query to a database, the problem is that the query works only when it receives the code AFG  ,  with any other countrycode (example DEL) returns nothing.
I haven't got conection error , using AFG code WORK but with any other that exists no

the database scheme is world -> city -> id , Name , CountryCode , District , Population

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db   = "world";


$respuesta = [];

$selec  = $_GET["selected"];

$ms = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    if (!$ms){
        $mensaje = 'ERROR: No pude conectar al servidor MySQL';
    }else{
        if (mysqli_select_db($ms, $db)){


            $q = "SELECT * FROM  `city` WHERE `CountryCode`='".$selec."'";

            $r = mysqli_query($ms, $q); 


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
                $cadena = '<option value="'.$row["ID"].'">'.$row["Name"].'</option>';
                array_push($respuesta,$cadena);


            }

        }



    }


    echo json_encode($respuesta);
    ?>
```

Comment: Show us the database schema or something to make an idea about the problem

Comment: Echo the query and run it directly in the database. Maybe there really isn't anything with that countrycode listed.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.